# How to pass an argument from a parent to a child componentin ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

In my child component(swipe.js) I have the following function:

```
 const swipeDir = (dir) => {
        if (dir == 'right')
            setXPos(300)
        else if (dir == 'left')
            setXPos(-300)
    }
```

And on the parent component I have this onClick button from which I wanna pass the value left to be used as (dir) in the swipeDir function.
This is how I have in the parent component  `<CicleButton onClick={() => swipeDir('left')}>`

How do I use the swipeDir function inside the parent component?

Comment: can you declare swipeDir in parent itself?

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the dir prop inside swipe.js. Inside swipe.js, use

```
useEffect(()=> {
  if (dir == 'right') setXPos(300)
  else if (dir == 'left') setXPos(-300)
}, [dir])
```

Inside the parent:

```
const [dir, setDir] = useState();
.
.
.
<CicleButton onClick={() => setDir('left')}>
```

Comment: `Error: Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-string-ref` 
I get this error

Comment: Can you show the code? Both parent and child?